# Access instance of class in callback anonymous function

Tags: php, class, closures

I have a class with a few methods that take an anonymous function as a parameter. The class looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public function myMethod($param, $func) {
           echo $param;
           user_call_func($func);
    }


    public function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello from MyClass";
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do things like this:

```
$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->myMethod("Hi", function($obj) {
    echo "I'm in this anonymous function";
    // let's use a method from myClass
    $obj->sayHello();
});
```

So, in my anonymous function, since I passed $obj as a parameter to the anonymous function, I should be able to access its methods from within the anonymous function. In this case we'd see

```
I'm in this anonymous function
Hello from MyClass
```

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `use` construct:

```
$self = $this;
$obj->myMethod("Hi", function($obj) use($self) {
    echo "I'm in this anonymous function";
    // let's use a method from myClass
    $obj->sayHello();
});
```

You've got to capture `$this` in another variable because `use` doesn't allow `$this` to be passed in, unless you are using PHP >= 5.4.  Relevant quote from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be passed to the `use` language construct. Inheriting
>   variables from the parent scope is not the same as using global
>   variables. Global variables exist in the global scope, which is the
>   same no matter what function is executing. The parent scope of a
>   closure is the function in which the closure was declared (not
>   necessarily the function it was called from).

**Update**

It may also be helpful to know that you retain the visibility of the class that you're currently in when the anonymous function is executing, as demonstrated in this simple script:

```
class Test
{
    public function testMe()
    {
        $self = $this;
        $tester = function() use($self) {
            $self->iAmPrivate();
        };

        $tester();
    }

    private function iAmPrivate()
    {
        echo 'I can see my own private parts!';
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test->testMe();
```

Output:

> I can see my own private parts!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I wanted to make the class publicly available and so trying to reduce what's needed to be done outside of the class as much as possible? Can I handle the 'use' case within the class?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your comment, are you asking if you put this functionality inside of a class can you also call private/protected methods on the `$self` object?